# Data.map is not a function TypeError: Data.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I had to modify Data.map is not a function
TypeError: Data.map is not a function how to be able to fetch data to display I think there might be a problem in this part because the data on the API side can be displayed normally but there is a problem in displaying the data.

Code

```
function Users() {

 const [Data, Datachange] = useState(null);
 useEffect(() => {
  fetch('http://localhost:3333/users').then((res) => {
    return res.json(); 
  })
  .then((res) => {
    Datachange(res);
    console.log(Data);
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
 },[])

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Container maxWidth="lg" sx={{ p:2 }}>
        <Paper sx={{ p:2 }}>
        <Box display= "flex">
          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
         <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
          Employer
          </Typography>
          </Box>
         <Box>
        </Box>
       </Box>
        <table className="table">
  <thead>
    <tr className="bg-navy text-white">
    <th style={{ textAlign: "center"}}>#</th>
    <th style={{ textAlign: "center"}}>name - surname</th>
    <th style={{ textAlign: "center"}}>email</th>
    <th style={{ textAlign: "center"}}>phone number</th>
    <th style={{ textAlign: "center"}}>address</th>
    <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      {Data && Data.map((item)=>{
      <tr>
      <td>{item.name_surname}</td>
      <td>{item.email}</td>
      <td>{item.phone}</td>
      <td>{item.job}</td>
      <td>
         <a className='btn btn-danger'>delete</a>
      </td>
      </tr>
      })
     }
     </tbody>
  </table>
       </Paper>
      </Container>
   </React.Fragment>

  );
};
```

export default Users;

Comment: check the `Datachange(res)` res is an Array? If not you should use `res.xxx` to get an Array for `Data`.

Comment: show us what is printed in console.log(Data);